# To convert Place Holder Value in another language in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used  Contact Form 7 plugin in Worpress and I also used Gtranslate Plugin to translate content of my Wordpress site into another language.
Issue is that Placholder values for Example Name, Email etc. is not getting converted into another language via Gtranslate plugin.It remains in default English.
Can please anyone assist me to fix this issue?

```
public static function form() {
        $template =
            '<p>' . __( 'Your Name', 'contact-form-7' )
            . ' ' . __( '(required)', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
            . '    [text* your-name] </p>' . "\n\n"
            . '<p>' . __( 'Your Email', 'contact-form-7' )
            . ' ' . __( '(required)', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
            . '    [email* your-email] </p>' . "\n\n"
            . '<p>' . __( 'Subject', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
            . '    [text your-subject] </p>' . "\n\n"
            . '<p>' . __( 'Your Message', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
            . '    [textarea your-message] </p>' . "\n\n"
            . '<p>[submit "' . __( 'Send', 'contact-form-7' ) . '"]</p>';

        return $template;
    }
```

Comment: You are using [WPML](https://wpml.org) plugin?

Comment: OP mentioned using 'Gtranslate Plugin'

Comment: But i think OP meant qtranslate

Comment: We have used Gtranslate Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/

Comment: I think you have to create two forms 1st for english and second for other lansuage when other language is called display second form.

Comment: @Deepaksaini But remaining site  are getting converted when I change Language Option. Is there no alternate way to fix it

Comment: Are You sure, that translate proper .po file for CF7 with language domain `contact-form-7` and generate .mo after that ?